# Giving a custom environment a name

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, environments

I have defined a custom environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,hyperref]{xcolor}     % Better control over color
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=DarkBlue, citecolor=DarkBlue, urlcolor=DarkBlue, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\questid}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenquestid}{#1}}
\newcommand{\questtitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenquesttitle}{#1}}

\newcommand{\givenquestid}{REQUIRED!}
\newcommand{\givenquesttitle}{REQUIRED!}
\newcounter {questc}
\newenvironment{quest}%
{
    \small
    \rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
}%
{
    \refstepcounter{questc}\label{quest:\givenquestid}
    Something goes here.
}
\crefname{questc}{Quest}{Quests}
\begin{document}
\begin{quest}
    \questid{1}
    \questtitle{Collect wolf pelts}
\end{quest}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to use `\nameref` to reference the environment by title. That is, I'd like to have `\nameref{quest:1}` spit out a reference that reads: "Quest 1: Collect wolf pelts."

How can I specify the name formatting within the custom environment?

Comment: Not only do you not include a preamble, where at least 4 packages are loaded, it appears that you are inputting file content that is not provided in your question.  It basically makes it very difficult to try to help you.

Comment: There. I fail to see how the content of the other file has anything to do with the question at hand, so I removed it. I've included the entire preamble with all packages being loaded so as to identify any potential conflicts.

Comment: Think about how you manage other references. For example, I use `fancyref` so I use its functionality to define the formatting of custom macros etc. Since you are using `cleveref`, it would make most sense for you to handle it that way. By the way, the preamble is a bit of a mess. You load `geometry` twice. You ought not load both `graphics` and `graphicx`. You ought not load both `color` and `xcolor`. Please edit your code to make your example a **Minimal** Working Example. The fact that you were asked to provide **a** preamble is no excuse for making an epic of it ;).

Comment: I have cut down all the packages. Cutting down the packages hasn't helped my understanding of how to assign a custom environment a name, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `\@currentlabelname` if you wish [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) to extract the appropriate content. Since you specify the question title using `\questtitle`, you could incorporate this addition using:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\questtitle}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\givenquesttitle}{#1}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{Quest~\givenquestid: #1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. I was trying to override the currentlabelname in the environment, not in the questtitle definition.

Comment: @Arkamis: I've added a small update to avoid problems with expansion when writing to the `.aux`. Also, I didn't see that `questc` might not be the same as `\givenquestid`.